# Hyperbolic Path Length

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

$\textbf{Problem}:$ Find the hyperbolic length of the path $t \mapsto t+i$ for $t \in [0,x]$.

Of course I immediateley considered the length formula:
\begin{equation*}
L(\gamma) = \int_0^x ||\gamma'(t)||dt
\end{equation*}

Where $\gamma$ is the path in question.

My question is, **how do I explicitly compute $\gamma'(t)$ here**? I attempted it and got $\frac{x}{y^2}$ for the integral but this doesn't seem right. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = (t,1)$, so $\gamma'(t) = (1,0)$. The hyperbolic norm is given by $\|\gamma'(t)\|^2_{\gamma(t)} = \frac{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}{y(t)^2}$, which in this particular case is...